Webservice for KYC (Know your Customer) and AVS (Age Verification System), that makes Age Estimation along with gender recognition
is there an AVS/KYC provider, that does Age estimation and detects the user's gender in the same step?
Amazon's AWS Rekognition can do this: https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition
But I'd like to have an all-in-one solution, that also checks IDs, if age estimation fails (i.e. the customer might be younger than X).
So, I need a service that does:

Record a video
does a liveness test
estimates the age
detects the gender
and does an ID verification in case there the video was not sufficient.

I looked at these services and also chatted with support, but they don't provide gender recognition form a selfie video alone (only form an official ID):
verifymyage.com
ondato.com
